# Does joining the same table but with different alias make difference performance wise in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider two queries:

```sql
SELECT me.* 
FROM my_entity me
INNER JOIN external_table et1 on me.external_id = et1.id
INNER JOIN external_table et2 on me.external_id = et2.id
WHERE et1.fielda = 'fielda_value' and et2.fieldb = 'fieldb_value'
```

Notice that `et1` and `et2` just aliases for the same table, e.g. the joins just duplicated.

```sql
SELECT me.* 
FROM my_entity me
INNER JOIN external_table et on me.external_id = et.id
WHERE et.fielda = 'fielda_value' and et.fieldb = 'fieldb_value'
```

Will they have different performance in posgreesql? Can postgresql optimize the first query into the second?

Comment: The queries will produce different results

Comment: Output is different, there is nothing to optimise for the database

Comment: I suppose it's because of `SELECT *`. Pardon me. I only need data from the main table, the joined ones are just for filtering. I've fixed the code in my question.

Comment: If you only need the main table, don't join, use an EXISTS query

Comment: Well, it's a little bit more complicated that it is in question. The code is generated by ORM, because I need to apply filters dynamically, and some filters require joining the same table, which produces the results as in the first example

Comment: If there is no UNIQUE constraint on the column `id` in the `external_table`, ie several rows may have the same `id` value, then both queries will potentially return different results : the first query will return the rows from `my_entity` and which match with two distinct rows of the `external_table` with the same `id` whereas the second query will only return the rows which match with one row of the `external_table`.